# Does EAP TLS benefit from “Verify the server’s identity by validating the certificate” setting

Tags: tls, certificates, wifi

For PEAP it's important to enable the "Verify the server’s identity by validating the certificate" setting in a Windows WiFi profile. Is there any benefit enabling this for EAP TLS? If I understood correctly, EAP TLS itself uses mutual authentication and does not require an additional certificate for server validation???

Edit 1. Picture added.

[image: Verify the servers identyty by calidating the certificate]

Answer (score 1):

> EAP TLS itself uses mutual authentication and does not require an additional certificate for server validation???

The **mutual** in *mutual authentication* means that both sides authenticate each other. This requires both server and client certificates. Failing to authenticate the server means that an attacker might impersonate the expected server, so that later data encrypted communication happens with the attacker instead.